# Adding Multiple images in flutter using function?

Tags: function, flutter, dart

I am not encountering any problem but I have a question as I have to add multiple images in my app. Suppose in future these images can get large in numbers so I just wanted to know that how can we use a function in flutter.

This is how I am adding images as for now:

```
        Container(color: Colors.redAccent, height: 2),
        SizedBox(height: 8),
        Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Image.asset(
                'assets/cat.jpg',
                width: 110.0,
                height: 100.0,
                fit: BoxFit.fill,
              ),
            ),
            Spacer(flex:1),
            Expanded(
              child: Image.asset(
                'assets/cat.jpg',
                width: 110.0,
                height: 100.0,
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

Expected:

[image]

My output:

[image]

Comment: You must use GridView with crossAxisCount:2.  please refer: https://codesundar.com/flutter-grid-view-example/

Comment: @Prianca do let me know if that didn't work

Answer (score 1):

[image]

As you used assets images in your code, so I am also posting the code for assets, you can change logic accordingly. Here is the sample code.

```
int _count = 0;
List<String> _listImages = [
  "assets/images/chocolate_pic.png",
  "assets/images/profile.png",
  "assets/images/loading.gif",
];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: _addImages, child: Icon(Icons.add),),
    body: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: GridView.builder(
        itemCount: _listImages.length,
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2, mainAxisSpacing: 20, crossAxisSpacing: 20),
        itemBuilder: (_, index) {
          return Image.asset(_listImages[index], fit: BoxFit.cover, width: 100, height: 100);
        },
      ),
    ),
  );
}

void _addImages() {
  setState(() {
    _listImages.add(_listImages[_count % 3]);
    ++_count;
  });
}
```

Comment: I will let you know this when I will add this.
As of now I have question on how to add a line on tapping one dot (I am thinking of adding a line as an image onTapping any of dot ) . So how can I achieve that?

Comment: If you can show me the screenshot of what you are trying to achieve I can help you better.